# Listbox selection to edit worksheet

Tags: vba, listbox

This question refers to this other: [Listbox populate with specifc rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071134/listbox-populate-with-specifc-rows)

In that case the listbox is dynamically filled with data of a database of a worksheet.

The question is:
How could I select a row (name) in the listbox and edit its reference of the worksheet? Ill explain. I thought of selecting a row of the listbox, then selecting an item of a combobox and confirm with a click on a buttom, so that the item of the combobox would fill a certain cell on the worksheet.

This is the userform

[userform2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5YOV.jpg)

Comment: with a userform, populate it with a ListBox, ComoBox, and the code to go with it, do you have anything to share ? edit your post with your code attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go by adding to your userform code pane the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Data() As Variant '<--| use an array to store data to eventually fill destination worksheet cells
    Dim destSht As Worksheet '<--| this will be set to the "destination" worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    With Me
        With .ComboBox1 '<--| refer to combobox (change "ComboBox1" with your actual name)
            If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit sub if no value selected
            Set destSht = Worksheets(.value) '<--| set the "destination" worksheet to the one with the name selected in Combobox
        End With

        With .ListBox1 '<--| refer to listbox (change "ListBox1" with your actual name)
            If .ListIndex = 0 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit sub if selected the listbox header row
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To .ColumnCount) '<--resize data array to match listbox columns number
            For i = 1 To .ColumnCount '<--| loop through listbox columns
                Data(1, i) = .List(.ListIndex, i - 1) '<--| fill data array with selected row data (Listbox.List is zero-based)
            Next i
        End With

        With destSht '<--| refer to "destination" sheet
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 5).value = Data '<--| paste listbox selected row values to selected worksheet after its column "A" last non blank cell
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

you should add a minimal handling of the "destination" worksheet setting to prevent invalid names processing

Comment: @AdrianVillicana: did you get through it?

Comment: Making progress. Thanks @user3598756

Comment: You are welcome. Please then mark answer as accepted. Thank you. Please also give proper feedback to [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196449/error-when-empty-listbox).

Answer (score 0):

I did what I could. Not very elegant.
The first column on sheet2 and on listbox is a consecutive number, so when click the listbox row I copy that number into sheet3, so I can identify the row on sheet2.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        With Worksheets("Hoja3").Range("A1")
            .Value = ListBox1.Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Then search for a match of whats on sheet3, on sheet2.

```
Private Sub asignar_Click()
    Dim z As Integer
    z = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To z
    If Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("Hoja3").Range("A1") Then
    Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(i, 21) = destinos.Value
    Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(i, 20) = ""
    End If
Next i
```

It works. The problem is I cant refresh the listbox after this.

I am grateful for your interest user3598756.